# Running the project on device is extremely long with my Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Everytime I want to run my project on my device, it takes at least 20 min to compile and run. The part that takes forever is the `Running 2 of 3 custom shell scripts` which correspond to the `Embed Pods Frameworks` -> `"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyProject/Pods-MyProject-frameworks.sh"`.

If I try to check `Run script only when installing`, then I get an error saying `App installation failed. No code signature found`.

I tried with another device it's the same. When my colleague clone the project and run it on his device it's really quick so it looks like it might come from my Xcode but I have no idea where to start to look for the solution.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I narrowed it down to this line:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign ${EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY} 
${OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS} --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements "$1"
```

I takes about a minute to sign each pod.

It does this with all my other projects.

EDIT 2:

Narrowing it a bit more, I executed directly this command:

```
/usr/bin/codesign -v --force --sign my_code_signing --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements path_to_pods_framework
```

Then when I go into the Console app of the macbook, I can see that:

[image]

Except that `ToutSaufVac` in `Volumes` just doesn't exists. And I have no idea how to rectify that...

Comment: have you tried to reinstall Xcode? 
force clean of your project?

Comment: I've tried, full cleaning of the project, deleted `DerivedData`. Haven't tried to reinstall Xcode as it takes time but might eventually...

Comment: Nico, I would recommend you to pluck up courage and go and edit the `Pods-MyProject-frameworks.sh`. Whatever is there you can at first try adding `echo 'foo'` between commands and `time` before each command. This way you will see what is actually taking time and what is hanging. Don't be afraid of digging there. Probably you will learn some interesting things. And don't reinstall Xcode because you will never learn what is there.

Comment: @StanislavPankevich yes definitively right for reinstalling Xcode. I checked my colleague's file and it's the same. He has the same cocoapods version. I even downgraded cocoapods from the latest beta version to the lasted final version, and still there...

Comment: Just add `echo FOO` to the beginning of that script, run Xcode again and observe build logs to see FOO there. Then add it before one string after another. Sooner or later you should see the bottleneck...

Comment: @StanislavPankevich check my edit.

Comment: Nico, I can't tell remotely. You could try solution suggested here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4149. Also there is notorious issue here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6675 but yours seems to be different one. Also you could try adding `codesign -v` (verbose) and generally look at `man codesign`, also at `--timestamp [=URL]` option which might be the cause.

Comment: @StanislavPankevich, I narrowed it a bit more. Check my edit. The `--timestamp=none` didn't change a thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129410/discussion-between-stanislav-pankevich-and-nico).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I revoked the certificates and created new ones. Simple as that...

Code signing went from about a minute for each framework to about 3-4 seconds!

Comment: This is obviously a great bug report for Apple. Do you want to open one with the details and link to this topic?